# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity - can't find issue

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-theme, android-styles

In my app, I'm finding some users are crashing with `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity` on my `MainActivity's onCreate()`.

The problem is that only some users experience this (and not all the time) and I'm unable to reproduce it.

There are two main things which I've checked:

1. Ensure all activities have a theme parent that inherits from an AppCompat theme
2. Ensure all Alert Dialogs use `activity context` and not `application context` when creating them

None of these things worked. Here is a sample of my manifest.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup,android:label"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">

<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/color_control_normal</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/dark_redr</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
</style>

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
```

I believe `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge` descends from an AppCompat theme (https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started#bridge-themes).

I've also tried to put `android:theme="@style/MyTheme"` specifically into the `MainActivity` activity tags in the manifest and that didn't work.

I could try to use `AppCompat` specifically in my theme, but I am worried about the unintended side effects with changing the parent's theme from a Material Design theme to a normal one.

Here's a stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package/com.package.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3654)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3806)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner (ActivityThread.java:5802)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:5710)
android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute (ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2267)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)

androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:846)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:809)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:195)
androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView (DataBindingUtil.java:303)
androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView (DataBindingUtil.java:284)
com.package.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.kt:134)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7963)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7952)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1307)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3629)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3806)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner (ActivityThread.java:5802)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:5710)
android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute (ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2267)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Line 134 of `MainActivity` is this `binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)`

Comment: Could you add the complete stack trace for your crash? It might give us some clues.

Comment: I've included some stack traces of the issue.

Comment: Can you post 'R.layout.activity_main' ?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced some issues like this. With some view components that require this, you need to specify the theme for current activity as Theme.AppCompat. Maybe you are using its descendant but just try the original.